# How to pass output of one procedure as an argument to another procedure in tcl

Tags: tcl, parameter-passing, proc

I want pass output of one procedure which is a list as an argument to another procedure.Below is a code which I have tried.

```
proc distance {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
    set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
    set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
    set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
    set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]

    set d [expr hypot($x2-$x1,$y2-$y1)]

    return [list $nd1 $nd2 $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2 $d]
}


proc processDistances {count threshold {filter ""}} {

 global node_


    set distances {}
    for {set i 1} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        for {set j 1} {$j < $count} {incr j} {
            # Skip self comparisons
            if {$i == $j} continue

            # Apply target filter
            if {$filter ne "" && $j != $filter} continue

            # Get the distance information
            set thisDistance [distance $node_($i) $node_($j) $i $j]

            # Check that the nodes are close enough
            if {[lindex $thisDistance 6] < $threshold} {
                lappend distances $thisDistance
            }
        }
    }

    # Sort the pairs, by distances

    set distances [lsort -real -increasing -index 6 $distances]

Inverse2 {*}$distances
}
$ns at 8.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 200 41]

proc Inverse2 {m} {

set result [open R.tr w]

lassign [lindex $m 0 2] x1 
lassign [lindex $m 0 3] y1 
lassign [lindex $m 0 4] d1
lassign [lindex $m 1 2] x2  
lassign [lindex $m 1 3] y2  
lassign [lindex $m 1 4] d2  
lassign [lindex $m 2 2] x3
lassign [lindex $m 2 3] y3  
lassign [lindex $m 2 4] d3   

set mt {{? ?} {? ?}}
lset mt 0 0 [expr 2*($x1-$x2)]
lset mt 0 1 [expr 2*($y1-$y2)]
lset mt 1 0 [expr 2*($x1-$x3)]
lset mt 1 1 [expr 2*($y1-$y3)]
set const {{?} {?}}
lset const 0 [expr {(pow($x1,2)+pow($y1,2)-pow($d1,2))-(pow($x2,2)+pow($y2,2)-pow($d2,2))}]
lset const 1 [expr {(pow($x1,2)+pow($y1,2)-pow($d1,2))-(pow($x3,2)+pow($y3,2)-pow($d3,2))}]

set x [expr {double([lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 0 0]  * [lindex $const 0]
                   + [lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 0 1] * [lindex $const 1])}]
set y [expr {double([lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 1 0]  * [lindex $const 0]
                   + [lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 1 1] * [lindex $const 1])}]

puts $result "x location of object is: $x \ny location of object is: $y"

 }
```

Error:

```
ns: processDistances 42 200 41: wrong # args: should be "Inverse2 m"
    while executing
"Inverse2 {*} $distances"
    (procedure "processDistances" line 32)
    invoked from within
"processDistances 42 200 41"
```

I'm getting output of `proc processDistances` successfully which is a sorted list but when I pass this output to `procedure Inverse2` using command `Inverse2 {*}$distances` written in `processDistances` (I have tcl8.5).I'm getting above error.Where I'm dong wrong.please help me out.

Comment: Got it to work to generate the error you showed. Then applied this fix to get it going further. But it generates errors after that because the lassigns are setting variables x1, y1 to empty strings. Key change: `Inverse2 $distances`

Comment: @Ron Norris I want `$distances` to take place of "m" which is argument of `proc Inverse2` and thereafter it should extract index value of `$distances` and `lassign` in `proc Inverse2`

Comment: By calling `Inverse2 $distances`, it passes the distances list variable to Inverse2 procedure (in place of "m"). Isn't that what you wanted? If you want it passed by reference, you can do that too.

Comment: @Ron Norris sorry I am not getting you. You mean to say I should add line at last to call `Inverse2 $distances`??or instead `proc Inverse2 {m} {` I should write  `proc Inverse2 {$distances} {` (by keeping `Inverse2 {*}$distances` in code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suggesting you run it just as I replaced it. If this does not work, I'm not sure what you're asking for.

```
proc distance {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
    set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
    set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
    set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
    set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]

    set d [expr hypot($x2-$x1,$y2-$y1)]

    return [list $nd1 $nd2 $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2 $d]
}


proc processDistances {count threshold {filter ""}} {

 global node_


    set distances {}
    for {set i 1} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        for {set j 1} {$j < $count} {incr j} {
            # Skip self comparisons
            if {$i == $j} continue

            # Apply target filter
            if {$filter ne "" && $j != $filter} continue

            # Get the distance information
            set thisDistance [distance $node_($i) $node_($j) $i $j]

            # Check that the nodes are close enough
            if {[lindex $thisDistance 6] < $threshold} {
                lappend distances $thisDistance
            }
        }
    }

    # Sort the pairs, by distances

    set distances [lsort -real -increasing -index 6 $distances]

#Inverse2 {*}$distances
Inverse2 $distances
}
$ns at 8.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 200 41]

proc Inverse2 {m} {

set result [open R.tr w]

lassign [lindex $m 0 2] x1 
lassign [lindex $m 0 3] y1 
lassign [lindex $m 0 4] d1
lassign [lindex $m 1 2] x2  
lassign [lindex $m 1 3] y2  
lassign [lindex $m 1 4] d2  
lassign [lindex $m 2 2] x3
lassign [lindex $m 2 3] y3  
lassign [lindex $m 2 4] d3   

set mt {{? ?} {? ?}}
lset mt 0 0 [expr 2*($x1-$x2)]
lset mt 0 1 [expr 2*($y1-$y2)]
lset mt 1 0 [expr 2*($x1-$x3)]
lset mt 1 1 [expr 2*($y1-$y3)]
set const {{?} {?}}
lset const 0 [expr {(pow($x1,2)+pow($y1,2)-pow($d1,2))-(pow($x2,2)+pow($y2,2)-pow($d2,2))}]
lset const 1 [expr {(pow($x1,2)+pow($y1,2)-pow($d1,2))-(pow($x3,2)+pow($y3,2)-pow($d3,2))}]

set x [expr {double([lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 0 0]  * [lindex $const 0]
                   + [lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 0 1] * [lindex $const 1])}]
set y [expr {double([lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 1 0]  * [lindex $const 0]
                   + [lindex [Inverse3 $mt] 1 1] * [lindex $const 1])}]

puts $result "x location of object is: $x \ny location of object is: $y"

 }
```

Comment: it's usually helpful to pinpoint your changes without cut'n'pasting all the irrelevant parts of the code.